# Sync ParticleSystem across Clients and server, Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to switch a single player game into multiplayer using unity 5.6.4p2 and c#.

I have two particle systems:

1. "enginePS" set to play on-wake which appears on all sides (cliens + server).
2. "engineSpeedPS" which set to play when player moving forward.

The second particle system does not appear only for localplayer the one moving forward, so others does not see the particle system.

I am new to UNet so I would really appreciate your help. please check my code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MP_PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
public ParticleSystem enginePS1, enginePS2, engineSpeedPS1, engineSpeedPS2, 
engineSpeedPS3;

private float verticalCurrentValue;
private float movingX, movingZ;

private bool zAxis;
public bool isMovingForward = false;
public bool isMovingBackward;

public float currentPossition;

public GameObject player;

void Start()
{
    engineSpeedPS1.Stop();
    engineSpeedPS2.Stop();
    engineSpeedPS3.Stop();

    verticalCurrentValue = movingZ;

    currentPossition = transform.position.z;
}
void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    movingX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
    movingZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

    transform.Rotate(0, movingX, 0);
    transform.Translate(0, 0, movingZ);

    ChangeEngineParticle();
}

void ChangeEngineParticle()
{
    if(!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
    {
        if (isMovingForward == false)
            isMovingForward = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (isMovingForward == true)
            isMovingForward = false;
    }

    if (isMovingForward)
    {
        if (!engineSpeedPS1.isPlaying)
        {
            engineSpeedPS1.Play();
            engineSpeedPS2.Play();
            engineSpeedPS3.Play();
        }
    }
    else if (isMovingForward == false)
    {
        if (engineSpeedPS1.isPlaying)
        {
            engineSpeedPS1.Stop();
            engineSpeedPS2.Stop();
            engineSpeedPS3.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using the [Command] attribute before CmdChangeEngineParticle(), but that made the engineSpeedPS to work at the server end only without being detected at the client end.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so your second engineSpeedPS can be ignored in the networking code - just play that locally on the client using isClient or similar.  It doesn't need to go over the network.

I'll talk just about setting the other ParticleEffect, which you want to play everywhere.  It is on a Client object, meaning that object is controlled by the client.  The client should tell the server that it's time to play the particles, and the server then tells all other connected clients.
The particles probably shouldn't play on awake, as everyone will awake at different times.

So you should have your own code that decides it's time to play the particles.  When it does it tells the server with a Command.  Note, this should be on the Player object - if not you'll need to Assign Client Authority.

```
[Command]
public void CmdStartParticles()
{

}
```

So the client in charge calls CmdStartParticles().  The [Command] tag means that it doesn't get executed locally, but on the server instead.

So what do we want the server to do?  It should tell all Clients to play the particles, and also play them itself.

```
[ClientRpc]
public void RpcStartParticles()
{
    DoStartParticles();
}

public void DoStartParticles()
{
    particles.Play();
}
```

The first function can only be called by a server, and it acts on all the connected clients.
The second function is just a handy way to actually do the action

In the CmddStartParticles function, you would just call RpcStartParticles() and also DoStartParticles() (because you want the server to also play them, and RpcStartParticles only affects the clients ).

Comment: Thanks for the replay, its really helpful that you explain the code and I do appreciate your effort. But it seems you misunderstood the idea in general. The particle system should not play for all clients at the same time, it should only play for the player who is moving currently. With the help of your explaination, I managed to make the particle plays for the player who is moving only. But other clients cannot see the particle coming out from that player. Its like the host does not sync the particle to other clients.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got your clue and have it done. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rip off the [Tanks Demo](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/tanks-networking-demo-46213), which I believe has moving things with engines which play Particle Effects.  It might be a bitt outdated, but should help still.

Comment: I will give that a look.